# PEP 517 method to specify build requirements is not working in poetry

Tags: dependencies, setup.py, python-poetry, pyproject.toml, pep517

How can I specify the "build system" requirements in poetry? I think [PEP517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) deals with this, but I can't get it to work.

I am using poetry to manage my project. One of my project's dependencies is built from source, and building the dependency fails because the tools needed during the build are not available.

The [dependency](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3364) has as `setup.py`, but no `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`. Following the discussion in [this poetry issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3364), I have tried adding:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
requires = [
    "packaging",
    "Cython",
    "setuptools",
]
```

to:

- the `pyproject.toml` file in my project (where the `poetry install` is initiated)
- a new `pyproject.toml` file in dependency's source tree.

*i.e.* building the dependency requires `Cython`, `packaging` and `setuptools`, as you can see from the first few lines in the dependency's [setup.py](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuQuantum/blob/main/python/setup.py).

Adding the `[build-system]` section doesn't seem to do anything The build appears to be done in a temporary virtual env, and that env does not have the required tools (`Cython`, `packaging` and `setuptools`).

BTW - I don't know if the `build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'` is correct (I think that means `setuptools` is being used to handle the dependency packaging, but I don't really know).

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency itself must provide a `pyproject.toml` according to [PEP-518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/) and list their build dependencies. There's nothing you can do in your project.

Comment: Hi @finswimmer, I think I have already tried what you suggest. The dependency never had a `pyproject.toml`, so I added one. The dependency's new `pyproject.toml` only contains the `[build-system]` section shown above (just those 7 lines, nothing else). Is there something wrong with the `pyproject.toml` I created?